# Can decorators be used to simulate trials?

Tags: python, decorator

Is there an elegant way to use decorators to simulate trials of some function, where the number of trials can be edited?

I expected this to work but it didn't. So I'm wondering how to fix it.

```
from functools import wraps
from random import randint

def DiceRoll(dice_size=6):
    return randint(1,dice_size)

def trials(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, num_trials, **kwargs):
        results = []
        for _ in range(num_trials):
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            results.append(result)
        return results
    return wrapper


@trials
def DiceRolls(dice_size=6, num_trials):
    return DiceRoll(dice_size)

DiceRolls(num_trials)
```

Comment: I see why it doesn't work (line: result = func(*args, **kwargs), but is there a workaround?

Comment: ``num_trials`` should not be a *parameter* of ``def DiceRolls``, but must be an *argument* of the decorated call. ``def DiceRolls(dice_size=6):`` and ``DiceRolls(num_trials=5)``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anything, the number of trials should be only a parameter of the decorated function:

```
def trials(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, num_trials=1,**kwargs):
        return [func(*args, **kwargs) for _ in range(num_trials)]
    return wrapper

def DiceRoll(dice_size=6):
    return randint(1,dice_size)

@trials
def DiceRolls(dice_size=6):
    return DiceRoll(dice_size)

>>> DiceRolls()
[5]
>>> DiceRolls(num_trials=3)
[1, 1, 1]
>>> DiceRolls(num_trials=5)
[1, 5, 6, 1, 6]
>>> DiceRolls(num_trials=5, dice_size=3)
[2, 1, 1, 3, 1]
```

Comment: Forgot to say thankyou, this helped me get my head around it.